# String matching using algorithms -python

Tags: python

The One and Only Ivan (Korean Edition)

The One and Only Ivan CD

The One and Only Ivan

The One And Only Ivan (Turtleback School & Library Binding Edition)

The One and Only Ivan

The One and Only Ivan: A Harper Classic

The One and Only Ivan Full-Color Collector's Edition

The One And Only Ivan

The One and Only Ivan

One and Only Ivan

Paris Match (A Stone Barrington Novel)

The One and Only Ivan

one string here is an odd one . 
How do i write a python script to take that odd one out

Answer (score 0):

Try `difflib.SequenceMatcher`:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
l = ['The One and Only Ivan (Korean Edition)', 'The One and Only Ivan CD', 'The One and Only Ivan', 'The One And Only Ivan (Turtleback School & Library Binding Edition)', 'The One and Only Ivan', 'The One and Only Ivan: A Harper Classic', "The One and Only Ivan Full-Color Collector's Edition", 'The One And Only Ivan', 'The One and Only Ivan', 'One and Only Ivan', 'Paris Match (A Stone Barrington Novel)', 'The One and Only Ivan']
print([i for i in l if all(SequenceMatcher(None, i, x).ratio() < 0.2 for x in l)])
```

Output:

```
['Paris Match (A Stone Barrington Novel)']
```

Comment: I need the output to be Paris Match (A Stone Barrington Novel).

Comment: @Pravesh Check it now it should work, please accept if it works

Comment: This isn't working with other outputs! Even this isn't properly working